# Go to an anchor point in a template with code in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

I have an Angular 4 application in which I need to add the following functionality:

There is a component with a list of objects. When the user double clicks on one of them, the app retrieves from a DB a list of objects and it should scroll to where the object appears.

I'd like to know how I could move to the desired position in the data once that it has been displayed in the browser. Right now, I have the following code:

```
let objElement = document.querySelector("#object_"+searchItem._objectID);
if (objElement){
    objElement.scrollIntoView();
    console.log("****** SCROLLING TO OBJECT");
}
```

The problem is that, the first time that I load the data from the DB, it seems that 'document.querySelector' returns null, as if the HTML wasn't 100% constructed yet, so it doesn't scroll to the position. If I try to locate the element again, it scrolls perfectly (as it doesn't reload the data from the DB).

Is there a "more Angular" way of doing this? I'm trying to find an example like this in the Angular Router documentation but I can't find anything...

**EDIT:**
To make things clearer, this is the pseudo-code that I run when the user selects an object:

```
if(selectedObject IS IN currentLoadedObjects) {
  scrollTo(selectedObject);  // This function runs the code above
}
else { // The object is in a different list, so retrieve it from the DB
  ObjectService.getObjectListFromDB(selectedObject)
    .subscribe((returnedList) => {
      displayObjectList(returnedList); // Basically, this function parses the returned data, which is displayed in the template using an *ngFor loop

      scrollTo(selectedObject);
    });
}
```

As you can see, I try to scroll to the object inside the 'subscribe' method, once that I have the data from the database and after I've parsed it. The object list is pretty big, so it takes 1-2 seconds to be displayed in the browser.

Thanks!

Comment: Its because u want scroll before data return from server. You need invoke `objElement.scrollIntoView()` after data reload.

Comment: Where did you put this code ? It should be executed after the DOM is ready. You should probably put it in the component's `ngAfterViewInit` function.

Comment: Hi! I've edited my question to give a bit more information about the problem.